# Trigger custom ribbon button click in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In my project I have a excel ribbon created with the XML like below

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" loadImage="LoadRibbonImage" onLoad="onLoad" ><ribbon><tabs> <tab id="AddInTabId" label="MyCustomRibbon">
<group id="Connections" label="Connections">
<button id="Config" label="Server Configuration" size="large" getEnabled="getEnabled" onAction="MyActionMethod" screentip="Server Configuration" image="Config.png" />
</group>
</tab></tabs></ribbon></customUI>
```

It works great when I manually click on the ribbon button. My ribbon button click event is handled in C# method so on click of button my C# method gets invoked.

Now I need to trigger this Config button click through a VBA code in excel. Please suggest how should I do it. I tried using commandbars as below but it does not work.

```
Dim b As CommandBarButton
Set b = Application.CommandBars("AddInTabId").Controls("Config")
If (b.Enabled = True) Then
b.Execute
End If
```

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure if this will work for you, but maybe you can have a look at it. It doesn't trigger the button, but with this you can Expose Code to VBA in a Visual C# Project. So basically your VBA method should be able to call your C#-method directly. (w/o using the button at all) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608604.aspx

Comment: Thank you. Will give it a try.